# Javascript: Are the escaped characters (\b, \f, \v) safe to use as concatenators for user entered data and localStorage?

Tags: javascript

According to [this document](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp) these escape codes (`\b \f \v`) refer to backspace, form feed and vertical tabulator.

I was thinking I could use one of these characters to concatenate some user entered data that I'm going to store in a localStorage key. As far as I'm aware there's no simple way a user would input one of these characters in a form field but I thought I would ask here to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, but it is not how you should structure multiple data into one string.

Instead format your data as JSON with `JSON.stringify`. And then to read those again, parse it to the original data with `JSON.parse`.

For instance, to store your input values:

```
let allMyInputValues = [
    document.querySelector("#input1").value,
    document.querySelector("#input2").value
    // ...etc
];
let json = JSON.stringify(allMyInputValues);
localStorage.setItem("myform", json);
```

And to read them again into the form:

```
let json = localStorage.getItem("myform"); 
let allMyInputValues = JSON.parse(json);
document.querySelector("#input1").value = allMyInputValues[0];
document.querySelector("#input2").value = allMyInputValues[1];
// ...etc
```

Comment: I'm using JSON currently actually, but I was looking to shrink the amount of text stored. As stringifying adds a lot of extraneous characters {}": etc

Comment: Just to demonstrate:
JSON ``[{"b":275,"t":"20:15","m":0},{"b":989,"t":"18:57","m":0},{"b":1071,"t":"15:33","m":0},{"b":332,"t":"07:43","m":0},{"b":1038,"t":"02:59","m":0}]``
String ``27520:15098918:570107115:33033207:430103802:590``

Comment: You should not worry about space. Have you checked the volume of data you can store in local storage?

Comment: Yeah I suppose you are right. I thought it might be faster to store/restore my data if it took up less space but the JSON stringify/parse methods are SO much faster than my homemade method I've decided it's probably not worth the headache.